# Increase/decrease buttons not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and have some experience with HTML and CSS and I am looking to improve my understanding on web dev as a whole. I am required to include buttons in the website I have previously completed and make more accessible by adding buttons to increase/decrease the text on the website. No matter what I try I cant seem to get my JavaScript code to work. Any help will be appreciated. My code is featured below:

```
// this section is to decrease/increase the text on the website

var content = document.getElementById("content");
var smallButton = document.getElementById("small");
var normalButton = document.getElementById("normal");
var largeButton = document.getElementById("large");

// this section is to decrease the text size

smallButton.onclick = function (e){
    content.style.fontSize = "10px";
}

// this section is to set the text to the normal font
normalButton.onclick = function (e){
    content.style.fontSize = "14px";
}

// this section is the increase the text font
largeButton.onclick = function (e){
    content.style.fontSize = "20px"
}
```

Comment: Btw you do code blocks by using three backticks on either side of the snippet like this: ``` ... multi-line code ... ```

Comment: first step: add some console logs... see if your code is running at all.  ````normalButton.onclick = function (e){
console.log("Normal button pressed");
content.style.fontSize = "14px";
}````

Comment: A good thing to do is to check your console for errors. You can access the console by using CTRL + SHIFT + J in Chrome.

Comment: When I tested this code, I found it is working fine for me. I guess one of the elements in your code does not exist.

Comment: Your js code seems fine. The problem may be in later code - so if you add another onclick event to the buttons, that will override the current onclick event. Use addeventlistener instead. Secondly, check that your html actually contains these elmnts.

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");

var smallButton = document.getElementById("small");

var normalButton = document.getElementById("normal");

var largeButton = document.getElementById("large");

const myFunction = (size) => content.style.fontSize = size + "px";
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    Content Size
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction(10)"id"small">
  Small Button
</button>
<button id="normal">
  Medium Button
</button>
<button id="large">
  Large Button
</button>
```

It works like that.

Comment: I think the questioner wants to know _why_ his code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend attaching an event listener like so:

```js
smallButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  content.style.fontSize = '10px';
});
```

It would also help if you included some of your HTML markup. Maybe your `<button>` elements or content `<div>` cannot be found on the page during execution of your script?

I have noticed that there is a lot of repitition in your code. There are various ways to improve this code. Some of these improvements are the use of a data structure, class, or a few data attributes to keep track of the state.

I would also recommend using `em` or `rem` units over `px` for overall scaling of content.

### Example using a data structure

You could make each of the buttons hold a state by supplying a data attribute that maps to the appropriate font size.

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

const fontSizes = {
  small  : 0.75,
  normal : 1.00,
  large  : 1.25
};

const changeFontSize = (e) => {
  const fontSizeEm = fontSizes[e.target.dataset.size];
  content.style.fontSize = `${fontSizeEm}em`;
};

document.querySelectorAll('.text-sizer-btn').forEach(btn =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', changeFontSize));
```

```css
.text-sizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.text-sizer-btn:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-sizer">
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="small">Small</button>
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="normal">Normal</button>
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="large">Large</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

### Example using a class

If you want to use class names instead of a JavaScript object, you can try the following instead:

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.text-sizer-btn');

const changeFontSize = (e) =>
  buttons.forEach(btn =>
    content.classList.toggle(`size-${btn.dataset.size}`, btn === e.target));

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', changeFontSize));
```

```css
.text-sizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.text-sizer-btn:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.size-small  { font-size: 0.75em; }
.size-normal { font-size: 1.00em; }
.size-large  { font-size: 1.25em; }
```

```html
<div class="text-sizer">
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="small">Small</button>
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="normal">Normal</button>
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="large">Large</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

### Example using only data attributes with styles

And here is an example using just a data attribute:

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

const changeFontSize = (e) => (content.dataset.fontSize = e.target.dataset.size);

document.querySelectorAll('.text-sizer-btn')
  .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', changeFontSize));
```

```css
.text-sizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.text-sizer-btn:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.content[data-font-size="small"]  { font-size: 0.75em; }
.content[data-font-size="normal"] { font-size: 1.00em; }
.content[data-font-size="large"]  { font-size: 1.25em; }
```

```html
<div class="text-sizer">
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="small">Small</button>
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="normal">Normal</button>
  <button class="text-sizer-btn" data-size="large">Large</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the questioner wants to know _why_ his code is not working.

Comment: @AD-1 Alright, I added some more details.

Comment: Good job, I think the questioner will be able to solve his problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're only dealing with three possible text sizes (small, normal & large), you can create CSS rules to handle each scenario, and from that you can add/remove those classes to `content` when you click on the buttons:

```
<style>
  .content {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .text-small {
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .text-large {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
</style>

<div id="content" class="content">THIS IS THE CONTENT</div>
<button id="small">small</button>
<button id="normal">normal</button>
<button id="large">large</button>

<script defer>
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var smallButton = document.getElementById("small");
  var normalButton = document.getElementById("normal");
  var largeButton = document.getElementById("large");

  smallButton.onclick = function (e) {
    content.classList.remove("text-large");
    content.classList.add("text-small");
  };

  normalButton.onclick = function (e) {
    content.classList.remove("text-large");
    content.classList.remove("text-small");
  };

  largeButton.onclick = function (e) {
    content.classList.add("text-large");
    content.classList.remove("text-small");
  };
</script>
```

Comment: This seems way more complicated. The questioner needs to know _why_ his solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach should solve your problem. I've already tested it. This way is a bit simpler, but it gets the job done.

```
<script>

function makeSmall(){

document.getElementById("textTobeChanged").style.fontSize = 10;
}
function makeNormal(){

document.getElementById("textTobeChanged").style.fontSize = 14;
}
function makeBig(){

    document.getElementById("textTobeChanged").style.fontSize = 20;
}
</script>
<button  onclick="makeSmall()">
    Small
    </button>
    <button  onclick="makeNormal()">
        Normal
        </button>
<button onclick="makeBig()">
Large
</button>
<div id="textTobeChanged">Text</div>
```